# error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular, api, observable

First time posting, so I hope I'm doing it right.
I have searched around for a far bit, but can't seem to find a solution to my problem.

I have the following code;

```
const GRAPH_CALENDAR= 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events';


getAfspraak() {
    this.http.get(GRAPH_CALENDAR).subscribe(
      afspraakdata => {
        console.log(Object.keys(afspraakdata));
        this.afspraak = afspraakdata.value;
      }
    )
};
```

Which keeps giving me the error:
`error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Object'.`

In the console 'value' is shown as a key.

The code does what it should on the local server, but keeps angular from completing the build for deployment.

Anyone knows how to solve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript does not know what keys are contained in `afspraakdata`.

Tricky way:

```js
this.afspraak = (afspraakdata.value as Record<string, any>).value;
```

Correct way:

```js
interface Afs = {
  value: string;
  //...
}

//...

this.http.get<Afs>(GRAPH_CALENDAR).subscribe(
  afspraakdata => {
    this.afspraak = afspraakdata.value;
  }
)
```